# Javascript compare Object array to a standard array based on value using regex

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays. 1 standard Array and 1 Object array.

How do I compare the two arrays based on a match then use the match on the left as a variable moving forward.

First Array

```
concaternated[
"Regression Scripts/WPF Scripts/Maps/Map Tools/Alerting Areas"
"Regression Scripts/WPF Scripts/Application Access/Application Logoff"
"Regression Scripts/WPF Scripts/Application Logon"
"Regression Scripts/WPF Scripts/Resourcing/Booking on / off - CW (incl TRLI)"
"Regression Scripts/WPF Scripts/Resourcing/Call Sign Transfer"
"Regression Scripts/WPF Scripts/Contact Directory/Maintain Contact Directory"
"Regression Scripts/WPF Scripts/Contact Directory/Contact Directory Methods"
"Regression Scripts/WPF Scripts/Maps/Map Favourites"]
```

Second Array (Object array)

```
folderHierarchy.path[
{ id: "2", outerpath: "Regression Scripts", innerpath: "WPF Scripts" }
{ id: "2", outerpath: "WPF Scripts", innerpath: "Application Logon" }
{ id: "2", outerpath: "WPF Scripts", innerpath: "Alarms Administration" }
{ id: "2", outerpath: "WPF Scripts", innerpath: "Application Access" }
{ id: "2", outerpath: "WPF Scripts", innerpath: "Contact Directory" }
{ id: "2", outerpath: "WPF Scripts", innerpath: "Maps" }]
```

I'm wanting to loop through the Object array and using the .innerpath value match this to first array using this regex

```
let regex = /([^\/]+$)/gm;
```

Once it finds a match then to use the match as a variable "parentpath" but only from the right side of the compare.

For example:
I'm looping through the second array using the innerpath value **"Application Logon"**

```
{ id: "2", outerpath: "WPF Scripts", innerpath: "Application Logon" }
```

And this matches the first array

```
"Regression Scripts/WPF Scripts/Application Logon"
```

I then want to set the variable parentpath as the first array match row....

Comment: IMO you're overcomplicating yourself, I don't think you need RegExes, a simple `split()` will do the job, then all you have to do is check if `yourObject.outerpath == arr[i] && yourObject.innerpath == arr[i + 1]`

Comment: I'm comparing the innerpath from folderHierarchy.path and the string from concaternated. not from the same array.